# How to remove a word from the URL with .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, web, anchor-cms

I want to redirect `blog.byperte.com/blog/article` to `blog.byperte.com/article`. The blog is built on Anchor CMS and has the following .htaccess file:

```
Options -indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you have parameters that are sent with the URL (blog.byperte.com/blog/article) such as article ID or title?

Comment: I think so. PHP is not my strong suit.

Answer (score 1):

To remove a file directory from a URL, use this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Make sure to clear your cache before you test it.

Comment: I will try it tomorrow and see how that will work. Many thanks!